# Wordpress : How to add a field in theme's admin form?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a checkbox to my theme's admin form but I am not getting any idea about how to do it..I don't know how to locate the exact file for editing. I have tried googling it but may be my search is something wrong for which I am not getting a proper solution.

Just for more clarity: I want the extra field in my theme's admin edit form which is used for setting up the homepage of the website.

Below screenshot is the page where i want the field to be added just after the **Sort Bio** field.

[image]

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: this link may help you https://www.taniarascia.com/wordpress-part-three-custom-fields-and-metaboxes/

Comment: there are lot of plugin to add extra fields for different form like "ACF, Type, Option tree" etc

Comment: which theme are you using ?

Comment: I am using AWE theme by CodexCoder.. I have edited my post to reflect where I want the field exactly.

Comment: Why is it with Wordpress, the first thing people say is "there's a plugin for that". You're meant to be developers. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields and make what you need for your own purpose.

Comment: Here you need to check your post_type then add a plugin 'ACF' by this plugin you add more fields for that post type.

Comment: Actually, what you all are suggesting is how to add custom field. But I want the field to be added in the theme's framework. I have added a screenshot of that page. In my wordpress admin, I have option to edit the theme's interface by adding static contents. There i want to add a new textbox.

Comment: I guess i am not able to properly explain my doubt.. :(

Comment: My theme has the homepage with different sections and to add/edit the content of the homepage sections, i can directly make the changes from admin without writing any code. So in that page I want to add a extra field whose content would directly reflect in the homepage of my site.

Comment: Hello Debs you want to this ?   http://prntscr.com/hnu4m7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add extra field for 'AWE theme' you need to add custom code.

1)  go on this location wp-content > themes > awe-wp > zels-framework >config

2)  select 'framework.config.php' file.

3)  go on line number 577 and add below code with modify according to you

```
 array(
          'id'          => 'new_fiield',
          'type'        => 'text',
          'title'       => 'New Fiels - 1',
          ),

            array(
          'id'          => 'new_fiield_2',
          'type'        => 'text',
          'title'       => 'New Fiels - 2',
          ),
```

https://prnt.sc/hnu4m7